# NetLogo: create half-moon around clump of patches?

Tags: debugging, netlogo

I would like to create "a half-moon" (yellow) around my splotch, created by in-radius function (blue).

I thought that I can simply use `in-radius value` for the blue one and `in-radius (value + 1)` for the yellow one. Then turn all yellow patches with `pycor < pycor` of patch in the center black.

[image]

Please, how can I write this condition into my code? or is there any easier solution? Thank you !

My code:

```
to setup
      clear-all
      setup-patches
    end

to setup-patches
  ask patch 0 0 [        
    set pcolor red
    ask patches in-radius 2 [
      set pcolor yellow    
    ] 

    ask patches in-radius 1 [  ; put the blue after yellow to be on the top
      set pcolor blue
    ]
  ]
  ask patches with [pcolor = yellow] [
    let ycor_center [pycor] of patch 0 0  ; how to write this condition?
    if [pycor] of patch-here > ycor_center [
        set pcolor green
      ]
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the NetLogo programming guide. Co-ordinates are explained at the beginning (in the agents section). When you refer to patch 5 3, you are referring to the patch with pxcor = 5 and pycor = 3. That is, patch 0 0 is already at the centre.

I have modified your code to use this fact and restricted the colouring to those patches with pycor >= 0 (that is, equal or above the centre).

```
to setup
      clear-all
      setup-patches
    end

to setup-patches
  ask patch 0 0 [        
    set pcolor red
    ask patches with [pycor >= 0] in-radius 2 [
      set pcolor yellow    
    ] 

    ask patches with [pycor >= 0] in-radius 1 [  ; put the blue on top
      set pcolor blue
    ]
  ]
end
```

Modified for the extended version:

```
to setup-patches
  ask n-of 5 patches [
    ask patches with [pycor >= [pycor] of myself] in-radius 2 [
      set pcolor yellow
    ]
    ask patches in-radius 1 [
      set pcolor blue
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you again @JenB ! ;))

Answer (score 0):

the running code for patches not located only in the 0 0 coordinates

```
to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
end


to setup-patches
  ask n-of 5 patches [
    set pcolor red
  ]
  ask patches with [pcolor = red] [
    let pycor_red pycor           ; create variable refering the position of one patch with pcolor = red
    ask patches with [pycor >= pycor_red] in-radius 2 [
      set pcolor yellow
    ]
    ask patches in-radius 1 [
      set pcolor blue
    ]
  ]
end
```

resulting in:

[image]

Comment: See my revised answer. You never really need the patches to be red, it's just being used as a marker (and then they turn blue). This is a perfect chance to use `myself` which refers to the asker (in this case, each of the 5 `n-of` patches taken in turn) and I am using `[pycor] of myself` to avoid all the turning red and assigning a temporary variable code.

Comment: Thank you again! that is great  - I was sure that there is simpler solution and I completely forget (and, honestly never really understood) utilization of "myself". I'll certainly remember it !